# BinaryWriter for 64bit files alternatives?

Tags: c#, 64-bit, seek, binarywriter

BinaryWriter - unable to perform Seek on 64bit values.
Parameter passed to the function Seek (int32)
Is there a similar class for files larger than 2 Gb?

Comment: Is there a reason why it matters? I don't mean to sound rude.. but surely the extra seek won't cause you any performance problems..

Comment: It's simple. I need to open a large file (previously recorded) and change a few bytes in it.
Code is already using BinaryWriter so I would not pass this class.
May be possible to do a Seek BinaryWriter.BaseStream?

Comment: File length is more 32bit (ie 2Gb for sign Int32)

Comment: Yes, call `Seek` on the `BaseStream` property.

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution to this problem is to seek the `FileStream` (which support `long` position) before creating the `BinaryReader`.

Comment: If the file is already open, can I use BinaryWriter.BaseStream to change positions? Or is this incorrect?
At least the current position I getfrom this class (BinaryWriter.BaseStrem.Position).

And in General whether the BinaryWriter normal write abroad 2GB ?

Comment: This may work but the result is not guaranted. From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.basestream.aspx) : _Using the underlying stream while reading or while using the BinaryReader can cause data loss and corruption. For example, the same bytes might be read more than once, bytes might be skipped, or character reading might become unpredictable._

Comment: Except he's using `BinaryWriter`, and you can avoid corruption problems by calling `Flush` before calling `BaseStream.Seek`.